# How to smear the results of a query efficiently

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table with two columns, one unique increasing `ID` and one `Transaction_Date` that is what it seems. I want to find the first `ID` of each hour, ncluding times when there are no transactions.

Trying this with Oracle I have:

```
WITH parameters AS(
        SELECT  TO_DATE('01/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') AS START_DAY
        ,       TO_DATE('08/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') AS END_DAY
        FROM    DUAL
), hour_range AS(
        SELECT  START_DAY + (LEVEL-1)/24 AS DT
        FROM    PARAMETERS
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (END_DAY - START_DAY + 1)*24 
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(HOUR_RANGE.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:"00"'),
MIN (T.Transaction_ID)
FROM HOUR_RANGE
LEFT JOIN Transactions T ON T.Transaction_Date > DT
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HOUR_RANGE.DT,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:"00"')
ORDER BY 1;
```

this seems to take a huge amount of time to run, even with an index on `Transaction_ID` and `Transaction_Date`.

Is there a better way?

**Added**

Attempt at the better way - still taking a very long time:

```
with parameters as(
        select  to_date('01/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') as start_day
        ,       to_date('08/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') as end_day
        from    dual
), hour_range as(
        select  start_day + (level-1)/24 as dt
        from    parameters
        connect by level <= (end_day - start_day + 1)*24 
), tx as(
        select  to_char(rt.transaction_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:"00"') tx_time,
                min(rt.transaction_id) min_tx_id
        from    Transactions rt
        join    hour_range   on rt.transaction_date >= hour_range.dt and
                                rt.transaction_date <  hour_range.dt + (1/24)
        group by to_char(rt.transaction_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:"00"'))

select to_char(h.dt,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:"00"'),
       t.min_tx_id
from      hour_range h
left join tx t on t.tx_time = h.dt
order by 1;
```

This is based on @DavidAldridge suggestion with some adjustments (I hope I have them right) because I forgot to explain that the date is a `TimeStamp`. Not sure if it works as it hasn't complete yet.

Comment: Does omitting `TO_CHAR` from `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` help at all?

Comment: @shahkalpesh - I need hourly breakdown - how can I do that without `TO_CHAR`?

Comment: When I ran the query using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1383) (by excluding the Transactions table), I am able to see 1 row for each hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
LEFT JOIN Transactions T ON T.Transaction_Date > DT
```

Every hour record is joining to every transaction record that is greater than it.

What you want is:

```
LEFT JOIN Transactions T ON T.Transaction_Date >= DT and     
                            T.Transaction_Date <  DT + (1/24)
```

Furthermore, you might consider aggregating the transaction records by trunc(transaction_date,'HH') prior to joining with the list of hours, then you can just issue an qui-join.

Something like:

```
with
  parameters as
    (select  to_date('01/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') as start_day,
             to_date('08/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') as end_day
     from    dual),
  hour_range as
    (select  start_day + (level-1)/24 as dt
     from    parameters
     connect by level <= (end_day - start_day + 1)*24),
  tx as
   (select  trunc(transaction_date, 'hh') tx_hour,
            min(t.transaction_id) min_tx_id
    from    transactions
    join    parameters   on transaction_date >= start_day and
                            transaction_date <  end_day
    group by trunc(transaction_date, 'hh'))
select    to_char(hour_range.dt,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:"00"'),
          min_tx_id
from      hour_range h
left join tx         t on t.transaction_date = h.dt
group by  to_char(hour_range.dt,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:"00"')
order by  1;
```

Comment: Edited. It's probably better for performance to pre-aggregate and then equi-join, particularly with a large data set.

Comment: Added some more to the question - had some difficulties and had to tweak some things - hope I didn't break it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to filter early, so I would do the group by before joining to the generated list of hours, eg:

```
WITH parameters AS (SELECT  TO_DATE('01/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') AS START_DAY,
                            TO_DATE('08/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') AS END_DAY
                    FROM    DUAL),
     hour_range AS (SELECT  START_DAY + (LEVEL-1)/24 AS DT
                    FROM    PARAMETERS
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (END_DAY - START_DAY + 1)*24),
        results as (select trunc(dt, 'hh24') hr,
                           min(transaction_id) id
                    from   hour_range
                    where  dt between (select start_day from parameters) and (select end_day from parameters)
                    group by trunc(dt, 'hh24'))
select to_char(hrg.dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mm') dt,
       res.id
from   hour_range hrg
       left outer join results res on (hrg.dt = res.hr);
```